# Windows Container: Containeradministrator vs. Administrator?

Tags: windows, permissions, docker, container

I am a little confused when it comes to the users with Docker. When I run a Windows Container (e.g. `microsoft/windowsservercore`) and I type in `whoami` I get the following response

```
user manager\containeradministrator
```

But when running `net user` within the container I don't see any `containeradministrator` but rather only

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            DefaultAccount           Guest
```

So what user is this `conataineradministrator` in the end and what permissions does he have? Does he belong to a user group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Net User' is being called from the HOST ( Windows itself not the container ) hence the Administrator only in the 'whoami'

'whoami' INSIDE the container is the container's equal which only has Admin rights INSIDE the container and things inside/acting inside the container.

Comment: Unfortuantely there are certain cases where permissions are different between Builtin\Administrator and manager\containeradministrator -
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/f426f708-a8fa-41a0-ac4c-4cacf48b1153/run-windows-2016-docker-container-as-administrator?forum=windowscontainers